# Custom loss function tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function

I'm try to test custom loss function.

i test how the network is learning base on tf loss function, and past it by me.
the result show that the network dont learn if i pass the function.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

def loss(y_true, y_pred):
  return tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=loss,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=7)
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

def loss(y_true, y_pred):
  return tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=7)
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

for the first code:
Epoch 1/7

```py
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 66us/sample - loss: 0.3035 - acc: 0.1015
Epoch 2/7
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 66us/sample - loss: 0.1481 - acc: 0.0994
Epoch 3/7
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 69us/sample - loss: 0.1097 - acc: 0.0990
Epoch 4/7
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 67us/sample - loss: 0.0875 - acc: 0.0991
Epoch 5/7
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 66us/sample - loss: 0.0770 - acc: 0.0989
Epoch 6/7
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 66us/sample - loss: 0.0665 - acc: 0.0991
Epoch 7/7
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 66us/sample - loss: 0.0598 - acc: 0.0988
10000/10000 [==============================] - 0s 36us/sample - loss: 0.0692 - acc: 0.0993
```

for the second code:

```py
Epoch 1/7
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 65us/sample - loss: 0.3002 - acc: 0.9119
Epoch 2/7
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 63us/sample - loss: 0.1458 - acc: 0.9561
Epoch 3/7
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 64us/sample - loss: 0.1066 - acc: 0.9680
Epoch 4/7
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 64us/sample - loss: 0.0875 - acc: 0.9727
Epoch 5/7
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 68us/sample - loss: 0.0738 - acc: 0.9768
Epoch 6/7
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 64us/sample - loss: 0.0662 - acc: 0.9787
Epoch 7/7
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 64us/sample - loss: 0.0575 - acc: 0.9817
10000/10000 [==============================] - 0s 35us/sample - loss: 0.0630 - acc: 0.9814
```

and its look like the loss is update but the acc is not learning from custom loss function

Comment: I think the problem lies in your training process rather than the loss function.

Comment: so why if i use specific the loss=tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy it work?

Comment: The loss is prebuilt in Keras. So why create a custom loss function?

Comment: I want to check if I can use custom loss function and be sure it work so I use the same function to be sure it won’t break anything and then use my own loss function.